# CodeIgniter 2.2.1 XSS filter removes tab character from post variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss, codeigniter-2

I have upgraded my CodeIgniter from 2.1.4 to 2.2.1. In this new version I noticed that the variables that are sent to the controller are being filtered even if I set the XSS filter setting to false.

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

This filtering unfortunately removes the tab character `'\t'` from the variable. So if I send some strings with tabs, the tabs will be replaced by space character.

Because I'm sending a tabular data (jqgrid) in one string and I'm differentiating each row with a tab (and differentiating each column with a pipe character) now the controller cannot recognize the rows any more (the pipe character was not removed btw)

How to disable this filtering? Or how to escape the tabs from getting removed?

Comment: Try reading `php://input`.

Comment: If you get the post variable with $this->input->post('varname', TRUE); you will get xss filtering even if the config is set to False.

Comment: @sotoz yes I know, currently I'm using $this->input->post('varname'); without the second boolean parameter

Comment: Hmm, check if you are using `$this->security->xss_clean` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Check if tabs are presents in $_POST['varname']. Maybe XSS filter isn't the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: comment line 320 in system\core\Security.php

```
$str = str_replace("\t", ' ', $str);
```